# Intel Max Brightness set to 937

Tags: intel-graphics, brightness, intel, backlight

I am trying to reset the `max_brightness` file in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` back to 15.  Currently, it is set to 937.  (I may have done this while trying to fix it). I have tried using `sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` to set the number back to 15, but it gave me a permessions error.  I had also tried `sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness <<< 5` which didn't work either.  If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.  Thanks, and have a good one.

Edit1

I have completely reinstalled `Ubuntu 16.10`, yet I haven't had any luck fixing this.  When reinstalling, I wiped my `Windows 10` partition, so information from there is no chance of accessing information from there.

Comment: On my system `...intel_backlight/max_brightness` has 444 permission, which suggests it's not accessible. I can use `sysfsutils` to manipulate `...intel_backlight/brightness` instead. Are you sure you changed `max_brightness` before, and if so, how did you change it?

Comment: @Zanna Sadly, I can't remember if it was me who changed it or not, as I would have made the change a long time ago.  My `max_brightness` also is displayed as read-only.  Not sure what to do from here.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Maybe that setting cannot be changed (no use fiddling with `chmod` in `/sys` I think). You can try this method of setting the default brightness... I don't know if that will be enough for you, but it is the standard way of controlling access points in `/sys` [Adjust Brightness 16.04](//askubuntu.com/a/772497)

Comment: no worries, please do let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: @Zanna Sadly, it didn't work.  I logged in and it was the same brightness as before.  I also tried to adjust it from `unity-control-center`.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  Do you think a copy of my  `intel_backlight` folder would help you?

Comment: Did you try different numbers there? You have to reboot of course, but I guess you did... I don't know what else though :(

Comment: Did you try `sudo bash -c "echo 15 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness;"`?

Comment: @StellaMaris Got `bash: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness: Permission denied`  I did run with sudo.